# Convert from sending email immediately from Excel to displaying in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

In this code an Excel file table from active sheet is sent directly via email.

I need to change it to same result only difference is I need it open in Outlook as draft and not send it (there will be added more of text etc.).

I tried `.Display` but it won't open Outlook new email, it is displayed in Excel.

```vb
Sub Send()
    Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Fill in the Worksheet/range you want to mail
    'Note: if you use one cell it will send the whole worksheet
    Set Sendrng = Range("B1:M44")

    'Remember the activesheet
    Set AWorksheet = ActiveSheet
 
    With Sendrng
        ' Select the worksheet with the range you want to send
        .Parent.Select
        
        'Remember the ActiveCell on that worksheet
        Set rng = ActiveCell 

        'Select the range you want to mail
        .Select

        ' Create the mail and send it
        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

        With .Parent.MailEnvelope
            ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
            ' some header text to the email body.
            .Introduction = "Dear All," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please find XXX." 

            With .Item
                .To = "XXXX"
                .Subject = "XXX"
                .Send
            End With

        End With

        'select the original ActiveCell
        rng.Select

    End With

    'Activate the sheet that was active before you run the macro
    AWorksheet.Select

StopMacro:
    With Application
```

Comment: Try by changing `.Send` to `.Display`.

Comment: change `.Send` to `.Display`. Once in Outlook, you can always send it manually. I couldn't understand what happens with StopMacro. Could there be some forgotten code?

Comment: Thanks guy, tried it but it won't open outlook new email directly, all is only displayed in excel. The stopmacro should be as part of code but ended as sub send on top outside of code post

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.Send` with `.Display`. If you want to wait for the user to either click on the Send button or dismiss the message, use `.Display(true)` to show it modally.

Comment: Any possibility to open it directly in new outlook email draft? Edit it there and send after?

Comment: That is exactly what `MailItem.Display` does - shows the message to the end user.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still not able to use it properly as I see...

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you getting an error? Or do you mean the message is not displayed?

Comment: I need something slightly different. All is good, I have all message displayed in excel file but I need from VBA to open new email draft in outlook directly to add attachments, make notes in copied table,add snips so this way. Thank you very much for your time anyway :)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean - MailItem.Display shows the email editor to the end user, where the user can type notes, add attachments, click Send. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. It's not as useful as in Outlook message when opened as draft as I need to change coppied table too. But thanks, I need to find other way.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean - it is exactly the same window that Outlook uses. How is it "not as useful"? You really need to be more detailed than that.

Comment: The code is coppying the table with values and format when send directly without opening any application. What I need is the same coppying of table displayed in outlook window to be able to change some values in it and then manualy send it. I don't know how to describe it more. As when I use.display I can't edit the table, just attachments, texts etc.

Comment: Use a function that converts Excel range to HTML and sets the `MailItem.HTMLBody` - see https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Comment: Thank you for your time but what I see is out of my capabilities

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Outlook directly from an Excel macro where you could display a new mail item to a user. For example, the following code creates a new mail items, set up properties on the item and then display it for a user:

```
variables declared as a specific object type ie. specific to the application which is being automated:
Dim applOL As Outlook.Application
Dim miOL As Outlook.MailItem

'Create a new instance of the Outlook application. Set the Application object as follows:
Set applOL = New Outlook.Application
'create mail item:
Set miOL = applOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 

With miOL

.To = "info@test.com"
.CC = ""
.Importance = olImportanceLow
.Subject = "Mail Automation"
.Body = "Sending the Active Excel Workbook as attachment!"
'add host workbook as an attachment to the mail:
.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
.ReadReceiptRequested = True

.Display

End With


'clear the object variables:
Set applOL = Nothing
Set miOL = Nothing
```

Don't forget to add an Outlook COM reference to your VBA project in Excel. See [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application) for more information.

Comment: Thank you but as I'm not used to programming, it's another world for me.

Comment: But you have posted a programming question, what did you expect to get as an output? A ready made solution?